# Comments on same line when code is split to two lines

Tags: c#, compilation, comments

I don't know if this is a silly question but I was asking myself why a one-line comment between some statements is working. Something like this:

```
string first = "Hello";
string second = "world";
string third = first + " " + // This is a comment
    second + "!";
```

The third line without the comment gets interpreted (and could be wrote) like:

```
string third = first + " " + second + "!"; // This is a comment
```

But what happens with the comment? Why is it possible for a one-line comment to sit in between a whole statement? I came up with the question when I noticed a method call like this:

```
someInstance.SomeMethod(parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3, // Some comment
    parameter4,
    parameter5);
```

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the compiler compiles the line until it finds the symbol // it ignores the rest of the line and goes to the next line automatically.